# How can i make the speed one the 5th floor manager computer the same as the main router?

Tags: networking

I'll write you a networking scenario and i want you to give me the answer ( if you have a network topology with " a router in the ground floor that connected to internet, a switch in the 2nd floor connected to that router with an access point connected to that switch, and another switch in the 5th floor connected to the 2nd floor switch with an access point connected to it, and there is the manager computer connected to that access point in the 5th floor, as we know duo to that series connection of switches that the speed in the main router wont be the same as the manager computer device, the question is, what can we do to make the speed in that computer be the same as the speed on the router) without any physical solution "do not change cable type or something like that", the only hint the teacher gave us is by using a technology, also vlans is not the answer.

Nothing, just wanted to hear the answer